# How to delete empty directories recursively without deleting parent folder?

Tags: java

Following function is used to delete empty directories inside backup folder. But problem with this method is it deletes backup folder as well if it is empty.

```
public static void deleteEmptyDirectoriesOfFolder(final File folder) {
    if(folder.listFiles().length == 0){
        folder.delete();
    }else {
        for (final File fileEntry : folder.listFiles()) {
            if (fileEntry.isDirectory()) {
                deleteEmptyDirectoriesOfFolder(fileEntry);
                if(fileEntry.listFiles().length == 0){
                    fileEntry.delete();
                }
            }
        }
    }

}
```

Assuming my folder structure is as follows,

```
backup
 -2019
  -10
   -15
 -2020
```

If I call method as `deleteEmptyDirectoriesOfFolder(backup)` it deletes `backup` folder as well. Any suggestions to fix it without including a second parameter to the method?

Comment: *"Any suggestions to fix it without including a second parameter to the method?"* - Create a second method ... for the subdirectories.

Comment: Create a `File` object corresponding to the backup directory and call `.exists()` on it. If it's not there, create it.

Comment: Are 10 and 15 directories, because if they are, it makes sense because then backup would be empty. If this is not what you want then just run a for loop through the subdirectories of backup, then call the method on its subdirectories.

Comment: yes 10 and 15 are sub-directories

Comment: Just delete the first two lines that conditionally delete the directory, and then only subdirectories of the orignal directory will get deleted. They are redundant anyway apart from this, and maybe the second occurrence risks an NPE.

Comment: NB You don't need two methods or an extra parameter, contrary to several answer and comments so far.

Comment: Removing first two lines will not work. For the last iteration of recursive call, input is folder `15` which is empty and it doesn't go inside the for loop, but `15` needs to be deleted.

Answer (score 0):

Have a wrapper class around `File` as below

```
class FileWrapper {
   private File folder;
   private boolean isRoot;
}
```

when you call `deleteEmptyDirectoriesOfFolder` for the first time, initialize `FileWrapper` as

```
File folder = new File("<backup_dir_path>");
FileWrapper fileWrapper = new FileWrapper(folder, true);
deleteEmptyDirectoriesOfFolder(fileWrapper);
```

then slightly change `deleteEmptyDirectoriesOfFolder` method as

```
public static void deleteEmptyDirectoriesOfFolder(final FileWrapper fileWrapper) {
    if(fileWrapper.getFolder().listFiles().length == 0 && !fileWrapper.getIsRoot()){
        fileWrapper.getFolder().delete();
    }else {
        for (final File fileEntry : fileWrapper.getFolder().listFiles()) {
            if (fileEntry.isDirectory()) {
                FileWrapper fileWrapper = new FileWrapper(fileEntry, false);
                deleteEmptyDirectoriesOfFolder(fileWrapper);
                if(fileEntry.listFiles().length == 0){
                    fileEntry.delete();
                }
            }
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer, but problem with your code is that after deleting `15` folder, `10` becomes a empty one too, but it is not handled here

Comment: @Channa fixed it.

Answer (score 0):

Your so close, just break it in two methods:

- deleteEmptySubDirectoriesOfFolder-Calls current method for all subdirectories
- deleteEmptyDirectoriesOfFolder-Your current method.

Here is the new method:

```
public static void 
deleteEmptySubDirectoriesOfFolder(final File folder) 
{
    for (final File fileEntry : folder.listFiles()) {
            if (fileEntry.isDirectory()) {
                deleteEmptyDirectoriesOfFolder(fileEntry);
                if(fileEntry.listFiles().length == 0){
                    fileEntry.delete();
                }
            }
        }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually...I'm very surprised that you don't ever get a **NullPointerException**. I think you should. Based on the directory structure example you provided, I interpret the tree to be:

```
- backup
    - 2019
        - 10   
            - 15
    - 2020
```

As your **for** loop within the **deleteEmptyDirectoriesOfFolder()** method iterates through the folders it does a recursive call against any sub-directory determined by
**fileEntry.isDirectory()**. A recursive call eventually gets to the sub-directory named **15** in which case a final recursive call is made. Upon that final recursive call the condition for the **if** statement above the **for** loop

```
if (folder.listFiles().length == 0) {
    folder.delete();
}
```

becomes **true** and ultimately the sub-directory is deleted and the recursive call is returned to the *previous* recursive call except now, because the folder (15) is deleted `fileEntry.listFiles()` becomes null hence when checking for `fileEntry.listFiles()` again (within the **for** loop under the recursive call):

```
deleteEmptyDirectoriesOfFolder(fileEntry);
if (fileEntry.listFiles().length == 0) { // HERE
    fileEntry.delete();
}
```

a **NullPointerException** should be thrown. You want to ignore the ones that are null so, you should perhaps check to see if **fileEntry.listFiles()** is null before attempting to play on it, like this:

```
public static void deleteEmptyDirectoriesOfFolder(final File folder) {
    if (folder.listFiles().length == 0) {
        folder.delete();
    }
    else {
        for (final File fileEntry : folder.listFiles()) {
            if (fileEntry.isDirectory()) {
                deleteEmptyDirectoriesOfFolder(fileEntry);
                if (fileEntry.listFiles() != null && fileEntry.listFiles().length == 0) {
                    fileEntry.delete();
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

If you don't want to also delete the **backup** folder if it is empty then just use the **for** loop (the **backup** directory should remain):

```
public static void deleteEmptyDirectoriesOfFolder(final File folder) {
    for (final File fileEntry : folder.listFiles()) {
        if (fileEntry.isDirectory()) {
            deleteEmptyDirectoriesOfFolder(fileEntry);
            if (fileEntry.listFiles() != null && fileEntry.listFiles().length == 0) {
                fileEntry.delete();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Your method should now function properly.

Comment: Yes your explanation is correct regarding NPE. But after fixing it, still I don't get the expected result

Answer (score -1):

Here is my solution after going through other answers,

```
public static void deleteEmptyDirectoriesOfFolder(final File folder) {
    deleteEmptyDirectoriesOfFolder(folder, true);
}

private static void deleteEmptyDirectoriesOfFolder(final File folder, boolean isRoot) {
    if(!isRoot && folder.listFiles().length == 0){
        folder.delete();
    }else {
        for (final File fileEntry : folder.listFiles()) {
            if (fileEntry.isDirectory()) {
                File parent = fileEntry.getParentFile();
                deleteEmptyDirectoriesOfFolder(fileEntry,false);
                if(!isRoot && parent != null && parent.listFiles().length == 0){
                    parent.delete();
                }
            }
        }
    }

}
```